Doorbell Camera on Vinyl Siding
I bought a Eufy S330 doorbell camera. I didn't realize until mounting that my doorbell button is just mounted to the vinyl siding. I looked at some vinyl brackets online. Then I thought, maybe I can just use really long screws.
What are the risks to securing a doorbell camera through vinyl siding into whatever is behind with long screws? or should I just buy the mounts?

It depends on how the house is built.  If wood studs built in the last 40/50 years, you might have plywood/OSB sheeting behind the vinyl.  An inch or 1.25 long screws should go into the sheeting which is plenty for door bell cameras.  You want to put caulking/sealant in the holes and on the outside/over the screws.
